# How to convert List<Asset> Array to List<File> Array in Dart | Flutter?

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, file, dart

I have List array which is based on flutter **multi_image_picker: ^4.7.14** dependency. How can I convert List Asset Array to List File Array?

This is the code

```
class _ConvertImageState extends State<ConvertImage> {
  List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> pickImages() async {
    List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();

    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 20,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets: images,
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
          selectCircleStrokeColor: "white",
          actionBarTitle: "Select Images",
          allViewTitle: "All Images",
          actionBarColor: "#3b3b3b",
          actionBarTitleColor: "white",
          statusBarColor: '#bbbbbb',

          selectionLimitReachedText: "You can select minimum 3 and maximum 20 images",
        ),
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    setState(() {
      images = resultList;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {......}
}
```

Can I do it with a loop? Please, anyone can tell me the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I find an answer. This is my working code. I think it is correct.

```
class _ConvertImageState extends State<ConvertImage> {
  List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
  List<File> fileImageArray = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> pickImages() async {
    List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();

    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 20,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets: images,
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
          selectCircleStrokeColor: "white",
          actionBarTitle: "Select Images",
          allViewTitle: "All Images",
          actionBarColor: "#3b3b3b",
          actionBarTitleColor: "white",
          statusBarColor: '#bbbbbb',

          selectionLimitReachedText: "You can select minimum 3 and maximum 20 images",
        ),
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    setState(() {
      images = resultList;
      putToFileArray();
    });
  }

  void putToFileArray(){

    fileImagesArray.clear();
    images.forEach((imageAsset) async {
      final filePath =
      await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(imageAsset.identifier);

      File tempFile = File(filePath);
      if (tempFile.existsSync()) {
        fileImageArray.add(tempFile);
      }
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {......}
}
```

**FlutterAbsolutePathClass (Dependency)**

*flutter_absolute_path: ^1.0.6*

Link: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_absolute_path

**To Print Array**

```
onPressed: () {
  print(fileImageArray.toString());
};
```